# PROBLEMA SALIDA DE EJECUCION NETBEANS

Tags: java

TENGO UN PROBLEMA EN NETBEANS, TENGO UN PROYECTO LLAMADO SISTEMA DE VENTAS, HASTA AQUI TODO BIEN, HICE UN PROYECTO NUEVO LLAMADO APPDB PARA PROBAR ALGUNAS COSAS PARA UNA CLASE DE LA UNIVERSIDAD, PERO ME DI CUENTA QUE EL PROYECTO SE HIZO TIPO "MAVEN", UTILIZANDO REFERENCIAS DE ESTE, OTRO INDICIO ES QUE NO ME DEJABA PONER LIBRERIAS, SOLO HABIA UNA CARPETA DE "DEPENDENCIAS", PERO BUENO, LE PIQUE A MUCHAS COSAS AL AZAR EN FILES, Y COSAS ASI PARA AGREGAR LIBRERIAS A LA FUERZA, PERO BUENO ME ESTRESE Y DISQUE ELIMINE EL PROYECTO, PERO LUEGO AL EJECUTAR MIS JFRAMES EN EL PROYECTO DE SISTEMA DE VENTAS AL DARLE "RUN FILE", ME APARECIA EL MENSAJE DE Target "default" does not exist in the project "appDb"., DE ALGUNA MANERA EL NETBEANS TOMA COMO RUTA DE SALIDA EL PROYECTO APPDB, YA PROBE DESINSTALANDO NETBEANS Y ELIMINANDO TODO LO REFERENTE A ESTE Y AL PROYECTO appDb, pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar.........., exporte el .jar para probar el proyecto en otra pc y ahi no ocurre ese error, cosa que me hace pensar que todo es problema de algunos archivos residuales de netbeans que no encuentro y que al instalar se autoacompleta esa informacion con netbeans (NOTA: YA VERIFIQUE EL BUILD.XML Y ESTA TODO CORRECTO, AL IGUAL QUE LAS DEPENDENCIAS, TODO)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Menciona en el título tu problema _específico_. 2. Ten presente que, en internet, mayúsculas sostenidas = GRITAR. 3. ¿Con qué versión de Netbeans estás trabajando?

Comment: Idem comentario anterior. Edita tu pregunta